# Print all possible pairs to change money using recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I've come up with this recursive solution to find the minimum number of coins to change given money for a set of coins denomination. It works fine but I want to extend this algorithm to print all possible ways to change the money but I couldn't.

Here is my code:

```
    static HashMap <Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); 
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int money=75,coins [] = {1,5,6};
    System.out.println(rc(money,coins));
}

public static int rc(int money,int [] coins)
{
    if(money==0)
        return 0;
    int mincoins = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0;i<coins.length;i++)
    {
        if(money>=coins[i])
        {
            int ncoins;
            if(map.containsKey(money-coins[i]))
                ncoins = map.get(money - coins[i]);
            else 
                ncoins = rc(money-coins[i],coins);
            map.put(money-coins[i], ncoins);
            if(ncoins+1<mincoins)
                mincoins = ncoins+1;
        }
    }
    return mincoins;
 }
```

I tried making a list of lists in which I store all the values for those I am making calls, but I am unable to put that in code.

So tell me how to do this if possible by extending this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call the recursive function just before calling it, add the coin to a global list. After the function call remove the coin from the list.

If your `money = 0`, then you simply print the list as that will tell you what coins you had to subtract to get to 0.

If `money < 0`, that means you overshot and subtracted too much and have to go back one step.

Ideone Link : https://ideone.com/aAQGdF

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone{

    static List<Integer> seq = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void rc(int money,int [] coins) {

        if(money < 0){
            return;
        }

        if(money==0){
             System.out.println(seq);
        }

        int mincoins = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<coins.length;i++) {
            seq.add(coins[i]);
            rc(money - coins[i], coins);
            seq.remove(seq.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int money=12,coins [] = {1,5,6};
        rc(money,coins);
    }

}
```

**Output** :

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 5, 5]
[1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 5, 1, 5]
[1, 5, 5, 1]
[1, 5, 6]
[1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 6, 5]
[5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[5, 1, 1, 5]
[5, 1, 5, 1]
[5, 1, 6]
[5, 5, 1, 1]
[5, 6, 1]
[6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[6, 1, 5]
[6, 5, 1]
[6, 6]
```